# reading from dynamically set filenames in R

Tags: r, perl, cgi

I am writing a CGI script in Perl with a section of embedded R script which produces a graph. The original data filename is unknown as it has been uploaded by the CGI script and is stored in a Perl variable called `$filename`.

My question is that I now would like to open that file in R using read.table(). I am using `Statistics::R` and so I have tried:

```
my $R = Statistics::R->new();

$R->set('filename',$filename);

my $out1 = $R->run(

    q`rm(list=ls())`,

    #   Fetch data
    q`setwd("/var/www/uploads")`,

    q`peakdata<-read.table(filename, sep="",col.names=c("mz","intensity","ionsscore","matched","query","index","hit"))`,
    q`attach(peakdata)` ...etc
```

I can get this to work ONLY if I change $filename into something static and known like 'data.txt' before trying to open the file in read.table - is there a way for me to open a file with a variable for a name?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to the only line that you are using `$filename`, which is `$R->set('filename',$filename);`, or did you make a typo and mean one of the strings in the `run()` command, where you put `filename` (no dollar sign).

Comment: Basically I want R to read a string variable, such as `$filename` as the data that R will process will be in a dynamically named data frame. I know R doesn't recognise sigils such as $, or @, but is there a workaround?

Comment: How many files are there in "/var/www/uploads"? And what's the extension of the file you want to read?

Comment: A very common mistake that many people make is that they assume that people that read their questions know things that they have no way of knowing. Such as, what this module is that you are using, how you are using it, how it is supposed to be used, what you mean by "setting $filename to something static" (isnt it already set to something static?). And also, you did not answer my question.

Comment: No, I get that, but it's difficult to phrase correctly. The CGI script I am writing will be accessed multiple times, and likely at the same time. The point of the script is to plot a graph using a datafile that is uploaded (into "/var/www/uploads" - hence there will likely be multiple files in that directory. I want to plot the graph using R. Earlier in the script the uploaded filename is stored in the perl variable `$filename`. R cannot read this variable and so does not know which file to open in `read.table`. I am trying to translate the information stored in `$filename` into a format ...

Comment: ... that `read.table()` can understand, thereby allowing the R interpreter to locate the relevant file and create the graph.

Comment: What I mean by 'setting $filename to something static is changing `peakdata<-read.table(filename, ...` to `peakdata<-read.table("data.txt", ...`. I hope that's clearer. Earlier in the script I copy `$filename` into a file I created called 'data.txt' and that's the only way R can read it it seems.

Comment: Are you getting nay error messages?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this is by doing a little more work in Perl.

This is untested code, to give you some ideas:

```
  my $filename = 'fileNameIGotFromSomewhere.txt'

  my $source_dir = '/var/www/uploads';

  my $file = "$source_dir/$fielname";

  # make sure we can read it
  unless ( -r $file ) {
     die 'can read that data file: $!";
  }
```

Then instead of $R->set, you could interpolate the file name into the R program.  Where you've used the single-quote operator, use the double-quote operator instead:

So instead of:

```
    q`peakdata<-read.table(filename, sep="",col.names= .... )`
```

Use:

```
    qq`peakdata<-read.table($filename, sep="",col.names= .... )`
```

Now this looks like it would be inviting problems similar to SQL/Code Injections, so that's why I put int the logic to insure that the file exists and is readable.  You might be able to think other checks to add to safeguard your use of user-supplied info.